# Google Autocomplete Address - How to change input id

Tags: autocomplete, google-places-api

(and sorry for my limited English).

I use google places autocomplete (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=FR) for an address form and I need to modify input id.

Currently the results are displayed in this form :

```
<input class="field" id="street_number"  disabled="true"></input>
<input class="field" id="route" disabled="true">
<input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true">
<input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input>
<input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true">
<input class="field" id="country" disabled="true"></input>
```

But I need to have something like that :

```
<input class="field" id="streetnumb"  disabled="true"></input>
<input class="field" id="rue" disabled="true">
<input class="field" id="ville" disabled="true">
<input class="field" id="departement" disabled="true"></input>
<input class="field" id="cp" disabled="true">
<input class="field" id="pays" disabled="true"></input>
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 3):

Create an additional object to resolve address types to your ids:

```
var componentResolver = {
  street_number: 'streetnumb',
  route: 'rue',
  locality: 'ville',
  country: 'country',
  ...
};
```

And in your fillInAddress() function change the last line of code from

```
document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
```

to

```
document.getElementById(componentResolver[addressType]).value = val;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I just changed the fillInAddress function to use the inputs name(getElementsByName) instead of ID

JS

```
function fillInAddress() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementsByName(component)[0].value = '';
            document.getElementsByName(component)[0].disabled = false;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                document.getElementsByName(addressType)[0].value = val;                
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<input class="field" name="street_number" id="streetnumb"  disabled="true"></input>
<input class="field" id="rue" name="route" disabled="true">
<input class="field" id="ville" name="locality" disabled="true">
<input class="field" id="departement" name="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input>
<input class="field" id="cp" name="postal_code" disabled="true">
<input class="field" id="pays" name="country" disabled="true"></input>
```

Comment: odd that they don't allow you to set your own ID's

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Maybe it is not the best solution, but working one. :) You can change id to whatever you want and handle it like this.

JS

```
  function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    document.getElementById('user_city').value = '';
    document.getElementById('user_country').value = '';
    document.getElementById('country').value = '';
    document.getElementById('user_zip').value = '';
    document.getElementById('user_city').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('user_country').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('country').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('user_zip').disabled = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];

      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        var field = addressType;

        if(field=="country") {
          document.getElementById('country').value = val;
          document.getElementById("user_country").value = place.address_components[i].short_name;
        }

        if(field=="locality") {
          document.getElementById('user_city').value = val;
        }

        if(field=="postal_code") {
          document.getElementById('user_zip').value = val;
        }

        if(field=="street_number") {
          var streetnum = document.getElementById('user_street').value = val;
        }

        // Join street number with street to one input
        if(field=="route") {
          if(streetnum) {
            completeadress = streetnum + ' ' + val;
          }
          else {
            completeadress = val;
          }
          document.getElementById('user_street').value =  completeadress;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<input class="field" name="user[city]" id="user_city" disabled="true"></input>
...
```